# Highlight a specific part of object in Unity

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, flicker

I have one problem, I want like a highlight an specific part of the 3D object, like a flicker of light that indicates something. In the picture, for example, i want that only the head and cheast can have like the flicker of light. Or any ideas that i can do to indicate that you can for example touch/click an specific area 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Halo" is what u seeking for..

-> Add component -> Halo.

Or

There is a better way since you used Canvas for your thing.

There is a component called "Canvas Group" which lets you control an "Image"'s alpha value.

Add component -> Canvas group.

You can place a canvas image on top of the selected area and change the placed image's alpha value and image color to what you like.

Comment: I tried with lens flare and halo and it didn´t work,maybe i used it in a  wrong way, and the problem of put an image on top is that the object have the component LeanOn that allows that you can zoom in/out or rotate it so the image won´t move with the object